# Was Napoleon Bonaparte short?

Tags: history, france

Is the common belief of Napoleon Bonaparte being a short person true? I've always believed it, but I recently heard that he was actually 1.69m (5 feet 7 inches), which isn't short at all.

Comment: 1.69m is really short for a man.

Comment: @mikeglenndale that was tall in 1800 http://ourworldindata.org/data/food-agriculture/human-height/

Comment: Already fully addressed on History.SE: http://history.stackexchange.com/questions/5519/was-napoleon-as-short-as-common-knowledge-states

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This was exhaustively answered on History.SE question "[Was Napoleon as short as “common knowledge” states?](https://history.stackexchange.com/a/5520/332)".

I won't provide the complete answer here - you should just read it on History SE - but as we can't close questions as duplicates cross-SE-site, I will offer just one cite from that excellent answer by @coleopterist:

> According to the French historian, Marcel Dunan (1963):
>
> "If one refers to the Memoirs of Marchand, t. II, 1955, p.338 "the total height of the crown to heel is 5 feet, 2 inches, 4 lines",
>   or (French measures) 32.47 cm X 5 + 2.7 X 2 + 0.22 X 4 = **1m 68.6**.
>
> These measures have been taken by **Antonmarchi** helped by Marchand.
>   For its part, the No. 8 (January 1963) Bulletin Quarterly information fields of French St. Helena, the Journal of Andrew Darling, **English upholsterer who was responsible for taking exact measurements** that I am assisted by General Montholon:
>   size 5 feet, 7 inches, or (English measure): 30.47 cm X 5 + 2.54 X 7 = **1m 70**.
>
> From these two stories we can conclude that the size of Napoleon was not lower **1m 68.6**"

For comparison, the answer offers:

> According [to this page](http://www.napoleon-series.org/research/abstract/population/vital/c_heights1.html) which cites "Steckel, Richard H. and Roderick Floud (eds.) Health and Welfare during Industrialization Chicago : University of Chicago, 1997" as a source, the average height of a Frenchman between 1800 and 1820 was 164.1 cm.

So, Napoleon was a mite taller than average Frenchman height.